# WinForm not sizing its controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

Just on some PCs, with "strange" video sizes, a WinForm app fails to correctly set the size of anchored controls. Strange e.g. a TV used as VGA device. Resize is working OK on Win7 desktops, but I need the app to work the same in conference rooms.

```
Private Sub frmSearch2_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ResizeEnd
    Dim s As String = ""
    s &= "me.size " & Me.Size.ToString & vbNewLine
    s &= "Me.ClientSize " & Me.ClientSize.ToString & vbNewLine
    s &= "dgv size: " & dgv01.Size.ToString & vbNewLine ' initially incorrect
    s &= "panel size: " & Panel1.Size.ToString ' initially incorrect
    Clipboard.SetText(s)
    dgv01.Width = Me.ClientSize.Width - (dgv01.Left * 2) ' manually set width based on ClientSize
End Sub
```

Executed on the problem PC:

```
me.size {Width=941, Height=578}
Me.ClientSize {Width=925, Height=540}
dgv size: {Width=939, Height=361}
panel size: {Width=964, Height=52}
```

Note the dgv is wider than the client area even though it is anchored on all sides. Height is resizing properly. I added a Panel docked to left and right edges to see if it would resize properly - nope. Changing AutoScaleMode doesn't seem to help - didn't try all possibilities. Remember: scaling works on most PCs properly.

The last line of code that sets the DGV width manually is visually OK. This would be OK for a very simple form but I have many controls, some hosted in other controls, that need the same attention.

Likely a video driver problem but the code shows the WinForm has the proper ClientSize, it just isn't using that value to resize the controls.

Is there something I can call to force the WinForm to reprocess the anchors using the valid ClientSize? Or??

Comment: Anchors, by themselves, should work.  It's not clear the roll of the panel in your setup.  Is the DGV inside the Panel?

Comment: The panel was just added to see if its anchors would work - they didn't. The DGV and panel as both on the form. The mystery continues...

Comment: Your question isn't documented well enough for us to see what is wrong.  We need to see the designer code and any other relevant code (Resize, etc).

Comment: Anchors often give me such problems too. I prefer using lots of panels and docking them, never had any problems since I do it like this. It takes a bit of work to put it all togheter, you have to get all panels in the right creation-order, but once it is done it works flawless.

Comment: LarsTech - this problem is reproducible with the most basic WinForm (in my specific environment.) I haven't made any changes to the designer code - nothing to document. GudidoG - been there - note the Panel in the OP isn't sized properly either. Most of my forms use a TabControl to host the bulk of the controls - that control doesn't resize properly either. Neither does the ToolStripContainer and other containers.  I guess I was hoping someone would recognized a VS/.Net bug that has a fix. This isn't an application programmer level bug.

Comment: This problem is with a fat client with 50+ forms so IDE level changes to each form is unlikely. I do have some common code that most forms call that passes a form reference. If there was something I could do to address the winForm/.Net bug in that common code that would be a good solution - something to "jiggle the handle" on the form to allow it to get/set the proper sizes.

Comment: Do your controls have deep nesting? How many layers?

Comment: At minimum three-four: form - tab control - tab - group boxes. Some have tab with splitter - panel. See "answer" below which seems to be working. The way we developed the forms the standard layout used default control names so the common code worked OK. I'm pretty sure the problem was some how related to video drivers on unusual devices like TV monitors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange problem... Some WinForms experience the problem and others don't. I haven't been able to determine the relevant differences.

The code below works 90+% for us as we have common names and positioning for significant controls on our forms that need to be resized on the problem PCs. A Panel - pnlResizer - was added to some forms that must work on the problem PCs - it contains most of the other significant controls.

```
    Try
        ' try to deal with bad video drivers
        Dim ctl() As Control = frm.Controls.Find("TabControl1", False)
        If ctl.Length = 1 AndAlso (ctl(0).Width + ctl(0).Left) > frm.ClientSize.Width Then
            ctl(0).Width = frm.ClientSize.Width - ctl(0).Left - 5
        End If
        ctl = frm.Controls.Find("StatusStrip1", False)
        If ctl.Length = 1 AndAlso (ctl(0).Width + ctl(0).Left) > frm.ClientSize.Width Then
            ctl(0).Width = frm.ClientSize.Width
        End If
        ctl = frm.Controls.Find("ToolStrip1", False)
        If ctl.Length = 1 AndAlso (ctl(0).Width + ctl(0).Left) > frm.ClientSize.Width Then
            ctl(0).Width = frm.ClientSize.Width - ctl(0).Left - 5
        End If
        ctl = frm.Controls.Find("pnlResizer", False)
        If ctl.Length = 1 AndAlso (ctl(0).Width + ctl(0).Left) > frm.ClientSize.Width Then
            ctl(0).Width = frm.ClientSize.Width - ctl(0).Left - 5
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```